# Making dropdown menu select required

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make required my dropdown but it should ignore the first option (Like please select).

Here is my code;

```
            <select class="styled" required>    
          <option value="">SEÇİNİZ</option>
          <option value="1">ADANA</option>
          <option value="2">ADIYAMAN</option>
```

Thank you.

Comment: you can easily ignore option 1 b'coz no value is defined there, in your javascript you can use `undefined` method.

Comment: You can play with index of dropdown list's selected value if it's 0 then validation occurs otherwise go on!

Answer (score 0):

*Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yDFF6/3/*

```
<select class="styled" required>
    <option value="" selected disabled>SEÇİNİZ</option>
    <option value="1">ADANA</option>
    <option value="2">ADIYAMAN</option>
</select>
```

You can add `disabled` to the `option` to prevent user from *actively* selecting it.

As per this doc: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-select-element.html#the-select-element

> ...If a select element has a required attribute specified, does not have a multiple attribute specified, and has a display size of 1; and if the value of the first option element in the select element's list of options (if any) is the empty string, ...

So, in your case the validation will kick in when the form is submitted, as the `required` attribute is specified and the value of default option is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <form action="demo_form.asp">
         <select required>
         <option value="">Volvo</option>
         <option value="saab">Saab</option>
         <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
         <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

now check for value of select

Comment: try here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_select_required